# How can I get response from HttpResponseMessage class?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I want to connect to my Web API from Windows Phone 8.1. The following code works for WPF. But when I compile it with Windows Phone 8.1 I get the `System.TypeAccessException` with additional information

> Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpContent)' to access security critical type 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' failed.

How can I get my data from Web API?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55424/");    

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/taxi/Nazwa").Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var users = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>().Result;

    lv_taxi.ItemsSource = users;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **await** the **ReadAsAsync** i.e.:

```
 var users = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>();
```

... which means the calling method must have the **async** modifier.

Without awaiting (or doing a synchronous **Wait**), the **Result** won't have a value when it is assigned to **users** (and to **ItemsSource**).

Comment: In this case the compiler is saying: "'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<App13.Product>' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<App13.Product>'"

Comment: My bad. I have corrected my initial response. Using await you don't refer to **Result**. Note that the issue is still the same... ReadAsAsync completes asynchronously which must be accommodated by either awaiting or performing a synchronous Wait (await is generally the better of the two)

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when a class makes a security demand and the application is not running in Full Trust mode but It shouldn't happend for the HttpContent class. I suggest you to use [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639) for Windows Phone apps instead. It has pretty similar functionality. Beside, it makes your code more [compatible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781239.aspx) with future WinRT apps.

> The System.Net.Http and System.Net.Http.Headers namespace might not be
>   available in future versions of Windows for use by Windows Store apps.

I know it doesn't address the problem, directly but probably solve the problem you are facing with.